# Running a file as script on cmd, file contains a function with two parameters.

Tags: python-3.x

I saved this file as "fib_test.py" .This function should print the Fibonacci between "n" and "o". It contains the following code....

```
def fib_test(n,o):
    a,b= 0,1
    while a<n:
        a,b=b,a+b
    while a<o:
        print(a,end=',')
        a,b=b,a+b
if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    fib_test(int(sys.argv[1]))
    fib_test(int(sys.argv[2]))
```

I am trying to run it on cmd as "python fib_test.py agr1 agr2" but its not working for me. I tried some other ways of passing the arguments but they also didn't work. 
Please suggest any solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call your function in wrong way. Correct one is:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    fib_test(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]))
```

Comment: Thanks.I figured that and was opening the window delete the question but you answered more quickly.... :)